# using mysql with hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I am having problem in using mysql via HIVE. When I do:

```
hive> show tables;
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

This is the section of the **hive.log** file:

```
2014-12-10 19:46:01,928 ERROR Datastore.Schema (Log4JLogger.java:error(125)) - Failed initialising database.
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is the section of **hive-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
```

but when I do the same query in MYSQL there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hive.log shows clearly that the issue is a failed attempt by the hive client to authenticate against the mysql database used by the hive metastore server.

You apparently do not have the correct root password for mysql.  You will either need to correct the password by obtaining from the sysadmin or reset it. Following are instructions on how to reset the password:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be 2 issues. One is your Hive service client or Hive server itself is not running. Second make sure the user has able to connect mysql.

Comment: how to check these services?